# PostgreSQL regex for email printing

Tags: regex, postgresql

I write this query but now i want to ignore all emails which have this string `abv` after `@`(both with upper or lower letters). Hope someone will help.

```
SELECT user_data.alternative_mail
FROM user_data
JOIN users_map
  ON users_map.user_id = user_data.user_id
WHERE users_map.service_id = 1 
  AND users_map.service_user_id = 0 
  AND user_data.alternative_mail NOT LIKE '%@abv.bg'
  AND user_data.alternative_mail IS NOT NULL 
  AND user_data.alternative_mail <> '';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ILIKE` instead of `LIKE` ([PostgreSQL Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html)) to make the match case-insensitive according to the active locale.

BTW: `LIKE` does not use regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT user_data.alternative_mail
FROM user_data
JOIN users_map
  ON users_map.user_id = user_data.user_id
WHERE users_map.service_id = 1 
  AND users_map.service_user_id = 0 
  AND user_data.alternative_mail NOT ILIKE '%@%abv%'
  AND user_data.alternative_mail IS NOT NULL 
  AND user_data.alternative_mail <> '';
```